# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TestComponent -> TestService]:

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am learning how to share a variable between two components with a service.

Component A (Service):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataSharingService {

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  data = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setData(data: boolean) {
    this.dataSource.next(data);
  }
}
```

Component B (component that receives value):

```
import { DataSharingService } from './data-sharing.service';

@Component({
  // component-specific configurations go here
})
export class Component1 {

  data: boolean;

  constructor(private dataSharingService: DataSharingService) {
    this.dataSharingService.data.subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
}
```

Component C (sets the value):

```
import { DataSharingService } from './data-sharing.service';

@Component({
  // component-specific configurations go here
})
export class Component2 {

  constructor(private dataSharingService: DataSharingService) { }

  // use the service to set the value of the boolean variable
  someMethod() {
    this.dataSharingService.setData(true);
  }
}
```

When compiling chrome shows error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TestComponent -> TestService]`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us what `TestService` looks like?

Comment: It is 'Component C'

Comment: `ComponentC` has an `@Component`-annotation, so it cannot be a service. To be honest: The code that you show us looks fine, which is probably the reason why you haven't got any answers yet. If you create a stackblitz-project with your code, there will be a 99% chance that I (or another SO-user) can resolve your problem quickly. ;-)